# Number of lines in cell of datagridview

Tags: sql, vb.net

How to get the number of lines entire the cell of datagridview ?
I don’t want number of cells or number of rows I ensure I want the number of the lines inside a specific cell.
thanks

Comment: The Value of Cell can be a String so simply split the String with the New Line character

Comment: Which query you tried

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question as it stands is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

This writes "2" in my Output window.

```
Dim dgv = New DataGridView()
dgv.Columns().Add("column", "column")
dgv.Rows().Add(1)
dgv.Rows().Item(0).Cells().Item(0).Value = "foo" & vbNewLine & "bar"
Console.Write(dgv.Rows().Item(0).Cells().Item(0).Value.ToString().Split(vbNewLine).Count())
```

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: First, thank you for your reply but it is not working properly with me it is not giving the actual number of lines.
I found a way to count the words it helps me now 


Button1.Text = DGVLog.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString().Split.LongCount

Or

Button1.Text = DGVLog.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString().Split.Length

Or

Button1.Text = DGVLog.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString().Split.LongLength

Comment: That might be because you don't have any new line characters in your cells (notice the one I have inserted into my string, vbNewLine) in which case you will only get 1. Now you say you started counting words instead, which is not exactly what you asked for initially, but good if it fulfills your need.